# Regular expression for __(' ... ')

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to get a regular expression to work and I'm having problems:
I want to match everything that starts with

```
__(' or __("
```

and ends with

```
') or ")
```

I tried with

```
/__\(['"][^']*['"]\)/g  and /__\(['"].*['"]\)/g
```

but they all have problems with this sample text:

```
text that should not match
__('all text and html<a href="#">link</a> that should match') text that should not match __('all text and html<a     href="#">link</a>')
__("all text and html<a href="#">link</a>") text that should not match __("all text and html<a     href="#">link</a>")
other text that should not match
```

who has the winning RegExp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the second example, use `*?` for a non-greedy match and consider using a backreference for the quotes.

```
/__\((['"]).*?\1\)/g
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jN0eZ9/2)

Comment: A non-greedy match (`?`) might be helpful, though we can't know that yet from the question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want non-greedy match, then the best solution is to use:

```
/__\(['"][^']*?['"]\)/g
```

Also, escaping the single and double quotes may help:

You can check it at this regex101

http://regex101.com/r/sM8yF9/1